# How to fetch a batch of data using tf.train.batch() according to some conditions?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a function 'read_and_decode_Train' which read and decode one single image and label from a TFRecords dataset. Then I use the tf.train.batch() function to serialized a BATCH_SIZE of images and labels to the images_batch and labels_batch. The code is as bellows:

```
image, label = read_and_decode_Train(tfRecordsName)
images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_threads=8, capacity=2000)
```

Now, I want to divide the TFRecords dataset into three subsets of training, validation and testing datasets according to some conditions, for example, if I have a csv file which rows are corresponding to the images and labels of the TFRecords dataset, then I divide the dataset according to the csv file. I modify my program to add a condition, which is as bellowing:

```
COUNT_TRAIN = -1    
def read_and_decode_Train(filename, csvLines, valNo, testNo):
    '''read and decode one single image and label
       from the TFRecords dataset.
    '''
    global COUNT_TRAIN
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=None)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    while True:
        features = tf.parse_single_example(
            serialized_example,
            features={
                'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'img_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
            })
        image = tf.decode_raw(features['img_raw'], tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image, [64, 64, 1])
        label = features['label']
        COUNT_TRAIN += 1
        if csvLines[COUNT_TRAIN][1] != valNo and csvLines[COUNT_TRAIN][1] != testNo:
            break
    return image, label

image, label = read_and_decode_Train(tfRecordsName, csvLines, valNo, testNo)
images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_threads=8, capacity=2000)
```

However, the tf.train.batch() function seems to read the data consequently as before.
So, in my situation, how to fetch data from TFRecords according to some conditions instead of reading data consequently?
Thank you for your kind suggestion and advice.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to instead split your data into 3 separate `TFRecords` files; one for training, one for validation, and one for testing.

Comment: Thank you. But if I want to do a cross validation, say, a 10 fold cross validation, I will have to split my data to 30 separate files. So I don't think this is a proper method.

Comment: Most SGD algorithms work best with batch sizes much smaller than the entire training data set. I think this divididing the data into folds should be done outside the TensorFlow graph for maximum flexibility (i.e. I don't see what tf can do here to help you).